# Chosen Ciphertext Attack textbook RSA

Tags: rsa

I'm trying to perform a chosen-ciphertext attack against an RSA oracle.
I have $c$ as the ciphertext I want to decrypt, $e$ and $n$.
I already know that I could choose a number $r$, compute $r^e \cdot c$, make the oracle decrypt, and return $r\cdot m$.

The problem is that this particular oracle checks if $m \bmod mo = 0$ where $m$ is the decrypted ciphertext I sent and $mo$ is the original message which I'm trying to get. If it's equal to $0$ *(like $rn$)* it won't print $m$ so I can't use that attack.

I don't really know what to do.

$n$ is pretty big (1024bit) so I can't factorize it. Maybe there is a small adjustment to the mentioned attack, but I'm really stuck. If anybody could give me a hint I would really love it.

Comment: What if you make $r\cdot m > n$? It will round via $\bmod n$

Comment: @kelalaka I think that $ r \cdot m $ should be less than n. I tried making the $r$ that big and I'm able to pass $m \mod mo = 0$ which is very good, but when i do $m/r$ is always less than 1 so i think that's not the right thing to do.  Sorry if i just changed the answer, i was making a coding mistake. $r$ it's just to big, when i devide by it  I always get a number smaller than $1$

Comment: Let  $m$ be the return value from the oracle, then $m = mo \cdot r \bmod n$ then $m = mo \cdot r + k \cdot n$ for some integer $k$

Comment: @kelalaka Thankyou! Now I understood, you were so much helpful.

Comment: When you succeed, could you write an answer?

Comment: What happens when submitting $c':=n-c$ ? Wouldn't the oracle answer $m'=n-m$, allowing to compute $m:=n-m'$?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help of @kelalaka i found a solution.

#### The idea

My exploit was based on the fact (I don't really know if it's always true) that if $r \cdot mo < n$ the oracle won't print anything, otherwise it will print some number, which unfortunate is not $r \cdot mo$.
So, $\lfloor \frac{n}{mo} \rfloor^e \cdot (mo^e \mod n)$ would produce no answer *($\lfloor \frac{n}{mo} \rfloor \cdot mo < n$)* while $\lfloor \frac{n}{mo} + 1\rfloor^e \cdot (mo^e \mod n)$ would produce an answer, even if uncorrect.

#### The solution

First I choose a number $r$ smaller than the original message $mo$. Then, until the oracle responds i keep sending $r\cdot 2^i$ increasing $i$ by $1$ each step.
When the oracle respond it means that I found a number $s = r\cdot 2^{i-1}$ such that

- $s < mo$
- $2s > mo$

Let $k:=\frac{s}{2}$. I iterate the following process until $k > 0$:

1. I send $s+k$.
2. - If the oracle responds it means $s+k > mo,$ so I assign $k:=\lfloor k/2 \rfloor$
   - If the oracle doesn't respond it means $s+k < mo,$ so I assign $s:=s+k$

In the end $s$ should be exactly $mo$.
The "algorithm" (it's a bit confused, I'm sorry) I proposed should get $mo$ in $O(\log_2 n)$ so it's tractable.